# What is wrong with the syntax for this insertion sort and bubble sort code?

Tags: python-3.x

I am  currently taking discrete structures and algorithms and have to work with python for the first time.

I am having a little trouble with the syntax and having a problem with my bubble sort and insertion sort function printing

```
def insertion_sort(numbers):
    numbers = [1, 5, 9, 3, 4, 6]
    for index in range(1, len(numbers)):
        value = numbers[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i >= 0:
            if value < numbers[i]:
                numbers[i+1] = numbers[i]
                numbers[i] = value
                i = i - 1
                print(numbers)
            else:
                break
```

```
def bubble_sort(numbers):
    for i in range(0, len(numbers) - 1, 1):
        for j in range(0, len(numbers) - 1 - i, 1):
            if numbers[j] < numbers[j + 1]:

                temp = numbers[j]
                numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1]
                numbers[j + 1] = temp


numbers = [1, 5, 9, 3, 4, 6]

print(numbers)
```

Comment: You are gravely mistaken with the scope of a variable, you have only defined functions and haven't called them, also you don't return anything. Either you removed too much while creating [minimum complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or you don't understand functions in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You've defined two functions but never call them. Therefore, they are not getting executed.
- You've defined your two functions such that they expect a `numbers` parameter. So you need to call them with a list of numbers as input. eg. `insertion_sort([1, 5, 9, 3, 4, 6])`
- Your functions are not returning any value. So they are simply taking the `numbers` list parameter, and sorting it. In order to access the result from outside the function, you need to add `return numbers` at the end of each function.

All in all, your code should look something like this:

```
def insertion_sort(numbers):
    for index in range(1, len(numbers)):
        value = numbers[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i >= 0:
            if value < numbers[i]:
                numbers[i+1] = numbers[i]
                numbers[i] = value
                i = i - 1
            else:
                break
    return numbers

def bubble_sort(numbers):
    for i in range(0, len(numbers) - 1, 1):
        for j in range(0, len(numbers) - 1 - i, 1):
            if numbers[j] < numbers[j + 1]:

                temp = numbers[j]
                numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1]
                numbers[j + 1] = temp
    return numbers

numberstosort = [1, 5, 9, 3, 4, 6]
print(insertion_sort(numberstosort))
print(bubble_sort(numberstosort))
```

This will print the output of each function. Output:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
[9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1]
```

Comment: As a side note, you dont need to return the list as this is a reference ^^. Good explanation for the rest, congrats !

Comment: With no return value, `insertion_sort(numberstosort)` will be equal to `None`.

Comment: Yes, but a `insertion_sort(numberstosort);print(numberstosort)` will work fine, it was just a side note

Comment: That's not true, it will simply print the original (unsorted) list.

Comment: When you redefine `numbers` at top, obviously that does not work, remove the return, the line `numbers = [1, 5, 9, 3, 4, 6]`. And try again. Not doing copy is also quite dangerous.